# Configuration JOOQ in JHipster

Tags: java, jhipster, jooq

I have a problem with the configuration of JOOQ in JHipster. I'm trying to use [petrikainulainen.net](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/using-jooq-with-spring-code-generation/) configuration in my testing app, but when I compile I have many errors. I'm using jooq-jhipster-generator.

My plugin generator

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>

    <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <!-- Manage the plugin's dependency. In this example, we'll use a PostgreSQL database -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Specify the plugin configuration.
         The configuration format is the same as for the standalone code generator -->
    <configuration>

        <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
        <jdbc>
            <driver>${jdbcDriverClass}</driver>
            <url>${env.DATABASE_SHORT_URL}</url>
            <user>${env.DATABASE_USER}</user>
            <password>${env.DATABASE_PASS}</password>
        </jdbc>

        <!-- Generator parameters -->
        <generator>
            <generate>
                <daos>true</daos>
                <records>true</records>
            </generate>
            <name>com.app3.jjg.JooqJhipsterGenerator</name>
            <database>
                <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                <includes>.*</includes>
                <excludes />
                <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
            </database>
            <target>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.myapp.jooq.todo.db</packageName>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
            </target>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

JooqConfiguration.java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.config;

import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource;
import com.mycompany.myapp.todo.JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;



@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JooqConfuguration {

@Bean
public DataSource source(){

    BoneCPDataSource ds = new BoneCPDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
    ds.setUsername("user");
    ds.setPassword("password");

    return ds;
}

 @Bean
public DefaultConfiguration configuration(){
    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

    jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()));

    SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(String.valueOf(SQLDialect.POSTGRES));
    jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

    return jooqConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnectionDataSource() {

    return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(source());
}

@Bean
public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
    return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyConnectionDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(lazyConnectionDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
}

@Bean
public JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer() {
    return new JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer();
}

@Bean
public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}


@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(source());
    return initializer;
}
}
```

Stack Trace

```
        2016-02-29 21:34:06.930 ERROR 3053 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#242533b6' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#242533b6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: transactionAwareDataSource,source,lazyConnectionDataSource,dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: transactionAwareDataSource,source,lazyConnectionDataSource,dataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#242533b6' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#242533b6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: transactionAwareDataSource,source,lazyConnectionDataSource,dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: transactionAwareDataSource,source,lazyConnectionDataSource,dataSource
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did you get that Java configuration code? Its trying to configure 4 different DataSources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear: you have defined 4 beans of type datasource. userRepository requires one datasource and so Spring does not know which one to inject.

> No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: 
>   expected single matching bean but found 4:
>   transactionAwareDataSource,source,lazyConnectionDataSource,dataSource

From what I see you expose all of them as beans but `source` and `lazyConnectionDataSource` are used to build `transactionAwareDataSource` so they should not be annotated with @Bean.

Then there is `dataSource` bean which seems to be created by spring boot maybe from your application properties.

Why using BoneCP when JHipster uses Hikari?

Comment: Thanks. I removed @Bean and DataSource configuration and now it's work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want all those DataSource to be beans. If you read the exception and look at the Java doc for those DataSource decorators it will tell you not to create beans from except the most outer one.

So the trick is to remove `@Bean` from all but the outer `DataSource`.

```
//remove @Bean
public DataSource source(){

    BoneCPDataSource ds = new BoneCPDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
    ds.setUsername("user");
    ds.setPassword("password");

    return ds;
}

 @Bean
public DefaultConfiguration configuration(){
    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

    jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer()));

    SQLDialect dialect = SQLDialect.valueOf(String.valueOf(SQLDialect.POSTGRES));
    jooqConfiguration.set(dialect);

    return jooqConfiguration;
}

//remove @Bean
public LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyConnectionDataSource() {

    return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(source());
}

@Bean
public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource() {
    return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(lazyConnectionDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(transactionAwareDataSource());
}

@Bean
public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(transactionAwareDataSource());
}

@Bean
public JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer jooqToSpringExceptionTransformer() {
    return new JOOQToSpringExceptionTransformer();
}

@Bean
public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}
```

You probably don't even need the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy as I believe BoneCP does something to this effect.